# Is there a cold storage option for altcoins?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin, coldstorage, hardware-wallet

Is it possible to create a paper wallet for altcoins offline and send your altcoins there?

I can only buy altcoins from online exchanges like bitrexx but I feel it's really risky to keep large amounts of altcoins there because it can be hacked, or my funds could be seized for some reason. Is it even possible to store altcoins safely in a cold storage or in a hardware wallet? I have tried to look for options but I haven't found anything. I wonder how people store their altcoins. Do they just keep altcoins worth thousands of dollars on exchange sites and pray that nothing bad happens?

Answer (score 0):

Each Altcoin will have their own respective wallet software. For example, Bitcoin has `bitcoin-qt` and SYS coin for example has `blockmarket-qt`. Each coin will have to have it's own wallet. Some wallets support multiple types of coins (Electrum).

Comment: Depending on the wallet software whether or not it is actually a cold wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest a hardware wallet. Trezor, Nano Ledger and Coldcard are all viable options for safe offline storage of bitcoin and all major altcoins.